# Sharepoint list return empty list although there is data

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem

I have successfully fetched data from the majority of my SharePoint lists without any issues. However, I'm encountering difficulties retrieving data from three specific lists. These lists have approximately 75 columns and 2,000 rows of data. but still in vain.

Note : using CSOM

```
 SPContextClient = new ClientContext(SPContextURL);
 List dataList = SPContextClient.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(ListName);

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = Camlquery
        };

        ListItemCollection spItems = dataList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        SPContextClient.Load(spItems);
        SPContextClient.ExecuteQuery();
```

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide to help resolve this problem. The time spent trying to retrieve data from these lists has been quite significant, and I'm eager to find a solution.